# Declaring local parameters in awk functions

Tags: awk

I am making some awk functions.  Local variables hove to be defined as arguments to the function.  Which can get quite long.  Is there any other way to do this?  If I continue the local variables, does one require some continuation character to add more variables on the next line?

```
function solarex_ltrul(categr, charcl,     ltrul)
```

Comment: Why not refactor or split the functions into smaller functions that take a manageable list of local variables?

Comment: The function is about 21 lines, so not too long.  But you are right to keep things quite compact.

Comment: just ending line with a comma should be enough, or you can use a backslash followed immediately by newline

Comment: @Heime : if you need only like 10-15 temp variables, just declare them all. If you actually need like dozens or hundreds of temp variables, then maybe declare a temp array instead ? Or get in the habit of variable recycling - say you have input variable `str0` then you need to split into an array and process in chunks, say, 8 characters at a time - once you `split()`, the original value `str0` is no longer needed. Then you can re-use it for something else. In addition, u can always treat `RSTART / RLENGTH` as temp vars, cuz they're already global but doesn't affect  `$0` in any shape or form.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at just the continuation issue in function declarations (I'm assuming that if it works for 3 variables, it will work for 30 etc)

```
awk 'function testr(xx,     out,
   mor) {
     print xx } 
     END {testr("hey")}' /dev/null
```

**output**

```
hey
```

and

```
awk 'function testr(xx,     \
    out,
    mor) {
    print xx } END {testr("hey")}' /dev/null
```

**output**

```
hey
```

hopefully answer your question.

(Agreeing with @jhnc 's comment above. I had tested this earlier, but didn't have time to post)

=======

As a complete aside, my testing was originally messed up by trying

```
awk 'function testr(in,     out....`
```

which seemed perfectly normal, but all  `awk` kept responding

```
awk:  bailing out at source line 1 in function testr
```

It would be nice if the error message was something like

```
**keyword without correct context**
```

or something like that.

`in` is a keyword for the `for (key **in** array)` context. /-;